# iOS AVCam Display image and prepare it to send to the server without saving it in photo library

Tags: ios, displayobject, avcam

so i'm looking for any sugestion about AVCam Controller. I'm used to UIImagePickerController but i need work with AVCam cause UIImagePickerController don't have enough options for me. Can some1 help me with display image taken from AVCam controller without saving it?

Looking for anwers,
thanks,
David.

Answer (score 0):

This is direct from Apple:  [How to capture video frames from the camera as images using AV Foundation on iOS.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html)